# How can i enable otg in symphony H250? which is unsupported otg phone

Tags: usb, usb-on-the-go

my phone doesn't support otg how can i enable this feature in my SYMPHONY XPLORER H250 android phone?

Answer (score 0):

Unless someone develops a kernel for it that adds support (which your phone likely never will - the fate of unpopular devices), there's no way around the limitation. Even then you will have to externally power the USB device in question (e.g. via Y-cables), since the port don't natively supply power.